# Chrome sound issues v 36+

Tags: chrome

After upgrade of Google Chrome to version 36, running Ubuntu 12.10<sup>[1]</sup> i686, there has been some issues with the browser.

---

***First*** problem was continued crashing. Typically after a short while the browser started to crash by the "Sorry, Jim", or what it is called, in various tabs. After some fiddling and searching I found increasing `ulimit` of *open files* halted the problem. (Mentioning this if it is probable that it has any connection.)

I currently use:

```
sudo sh -c "ulimit -n 8192 && exec su $LOGNAME"
```

and run Chrome from that terminal. This has ended the crashes.

---

***Second*** problem is that *sometimes* media is stuttering.

Typically on Youtube and other streaming media. The sound goes in about 4-500ms *"bursts"* with a lot of distortion. Making e.g. speech very difficult to decipher. Sometimes a simple refresh of the page (<kbd>F5</kbd>) fixes the issue, but usually I have to close down a lot of windows etc before it is going back to normal. The memory or CPU is *"normal"* when this occurs. Have not had this problem with earlier versions, even when RAM go over in swap.

Anyone having similar issues? Know what to do, how to track down cause etc.?

Using Pulse Audio as sound server.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> *Note on Ubuntu version: Know it is EOL, (May 2014), but I have to invest in a HDD for backup etc. before I can do an upgrade (or likely install a different distro.) Stuck running UB 12.10 until then.*

Comment: This sounds dumb, but have you rebooted after the upgrade? I'm having IT Crowd flashbacks...

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Yes I have *tried turning it off and on again* ;)